# Trying to find IndexOf a quote character

Tags: powershell, character-encoding, escaping, substring, indexof

Full string:

PDFReference =

```
javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("InvestorL
    ibrary_ILTocUC$LandingPanel$ildetail$lbNext", "", false, "", "/AO/Main.aspx?did
     = 003711812@bull!nb2016!n160550603", false, true))
```

From the above I only want to capture `003711812@bull!nb2016!n160550603`

So here is what I am trying:

```
$PDFDid = $PDFReference.Substring($PDFReference.IndexOf('?did = ') + 7, ($PDFReference.IndexOf('?did = ') + 7 ) - ($PDFReference.IndexOf("`"")))
```

My issue is with the `$PDFReference.IndexOf("`"")` as this seems to be the cleanest way to capture the full string but I am getting an error

```
Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "Index and length must refer to a location within the 
string.
Parameter name: length"
```

Any ideas how to perform `IndexOf` a `"` character? I've tried using `"`, `&quot;`, and `&#34;` but none of these encodings work either. It won't recognize the quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already doing the `IndexOf` right, although I would use `.indexOf('"')`. The error relies on the `Substring`. However, I wouldn't go this way...

---

You could easy capture the string using a simple regex:

```
\?did\s+=\s+([^"]*)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**PowerShell**:

```
$PDFDid = [regex]::Match($PDFReference , '\?did\s+=\s+([^"]*)').Groups[1].Value
```

Comment: Amazing. Exactly what I needed. I will now try to dissect that to make sure I fully understand it moving forward. Thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer and added some information to your original problem. However, regex suits perfect here since you want to capture a string where you otherwise have to use some `indexof` and `substring` which is much harder to read IMHO.

Comment: You can find more information on that regex here: https://regex101.com/r/iN9hR2/1